# Why does a compact-open topology define a subbase of continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Why does a *compact-open topology* define a *subbase* of *continuous functions*?

It is clear that in order for a set of such functions to set a *subbase*, it must cover the space of all continuous functions of their $X$ in $Y$, but it seems to me not obvious that in some arbitrary topological space there will be a union of such compacts that the function we need will be defined on it.

As I understand it, the answer to this question should be obvious, but still I don't understand why this is so.I will be grateful for any reasoning.

Comment: I don't think there are any conditions a prebase needs to satisfy. Given any set $Z$ and any family of subsets $\mathcal{B}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a pre-base for the topology $\tau$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: What is your definition of prebase? I haven't encountered this term before -- is it the same as subbase/subbasis?

Comment: @Yanko the first axiom of topology on the set X is that X is contained in this topology, but how can we get all X if not every point of X has the element of the prebase in which it consists

Comment: @diracdeltafunk it is the same as subbase

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that question. The topology generated by $\mathcal B$ on $X$ by definition contains $\varnothing$ and $X$, for example.

Comment: Then @Yanko is correct -- a "prebase for a topology on $X$" is literally just another name for "a set of subsets of $X$". You take the intersection of all topologies containing the prebase to get the topology it generates.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk  A prebase is a set of subsets in X such that the set of its unions and intersections defines a topology on X. Here is the definition, I think the point is that our definitions are not the same

Comment: Any finite subset of $X$ is compact.  Let $F$ be a finite subset of $X$.  The set of all continuous functions that map $F$ into $Y$ is a single sub-base set which covers the entire space of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: I think you mean something like "a set of subsets of $X$ such that its set of unions of finite intersections is a topology on $X$". But in fact *every* set of subsets of $X$ satisfies this condition. A prebase is nothing more than a collection of subsets of $X$, with no additional conditions.

Comment: For example, you get $X$ as the empty intersection of subsets of $X$, and $\varnothing$ as the empty union of subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "prebase" is a bit unusual, most frequently one uses the word *[subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase)*.

Given a set $X$ and a set $\Sigma$ of subsets of $X$, there is a coarsest topology $\mathcal T(\Sigma)$ containing $\Sigma$. It is called the *topology generated by $\Sigma$*. Explicitly it can be described as follows:

1. Let $\mathcal B(\Sigma)$ be the set of all finite intersections of elements of $\Sigma$. That is,
   $$\mathcal B(\Sigma) = \{ \bigcap_{S \in F} S \mid F \subset \Sigma \text{ is finite }\}.$$
   $F = \emptyset$ is allowed and one understands $\bigcap_{S \in \emptyset} S = X$. This is because for $x \in X$  we have $x \in \bigcap_{S \in F} S$ iff $x \in S$ for all $S \in F$. If $F = \emptyset$, then each $x \in X$ satisfies $x \in \bigcap_{S \in \emptyset} S$ for all $S \in  \emptyset$, simply because there are no such $S$.
   Clearly $\Sigma \subset \mathcal B(\Sigma)$.
2. Take $\mathcal T(\Sigma)$ to be set of unions of elements of $\mathcal B(\Sigma)$. That is,
   $$\mathcal T(\Sigma) = \{ \bigcup_{B \in M} B \mid M \subset \mathcal B(\Sigma)\}.$$
   For $M = \emptyset$ we understand $\bigcup_{B \in \emptyset} B = \emptyset$. The argument is similar as above.
   Clearly $\mathcal B(\Sigma) \subset \mathcal T(\Sigma)$.

A *subbase for a given topology $\mathcal T$ on a set $X$* is a subset $\Sigma \subset \mathcal T$ which generates $\mathcal T$. This means that $\mathcal T(\Sigma) = \mathcal T$.

Given as above **any** set system $\Sigma$ on a set $X$, then trivially $\Sigma$ is a subbase for the topology $\mathcal T(\Sigma)$.

Let us consider the set $C(X,Y)$ of continuous functions $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces $X,Y$. Thus is just a set, but we can define various topologies on $C(X,Y)$ to make it a *function space*. A standard topology on $C(X,Y)$ is the *compact-open topology* $\mathcal T_{co}$. It is defined as the topology generated by
$$\Sigma_{co} = \{ \langle K, U \rangle  \mid  K \subset K \text{ compact}, U \subset Y \text{open}\} .$$
Here $\langle K, U \rangle = \{ f \in C(X,Y)  \mid f(K) \subset U \}$. By the way, $C(X,Y) = \langle \emptyset, Y \rangle \in \Sigma_{co}$.

Your question

> Why does a compact-open topology define a prebase of continuous functions?

is a bit unclear. The compact-open topology $\mathcal T_{co}$ has $\Sigma_{co}$ as a subbase, but $\mathcal T_{co}$ does not **define** $\Sigma_{co}$ as a subbase. On the contrary,  $\mathcal T_{co}$ **is defined** by starting with $\Sigma_{co}$.