# Subbase for a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. A collection $\mathcal{S}$ of its open subsets is a
subbase for $\tau$ provided that the collection

$$\mathcal{B}=\{V\mid V=\cap_{i=1}^k W_i, k\in \mathbb{N}, W_i\in \mathcal{S}\} $$

is a base for $\tau$.

How can I show the following:

Let for any set $X$, $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of its subsets. Prove that $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for a topology in $X$ if and only if $X=\cup_{W\in \mathcal{S}}W$.

I have proved one side that if union of members of $\mathcal{S}$ is $X$, then $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase. I am not able to prove the converse.

Comment: I take issue with this question. The correct convention is that the empty intersection of subsets of $X$ is equal to $X$, and so every collection of subsets of $X$ is a subbase for a topology on $X$.

Comment: But let's put this aside and suppose $\mathbb{N}$ here is meant to denote the positive integers. The first step to solving this problem is: assuming $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for a topology $\tau$, can you write $\tau$ in terms of $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: Then, per your edit: to prove the converse, assume $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for a topology $\tau$. By definition of topology, $X \in \tau$. Using step 1 (see previous comment), what does this say about $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: As per the definition, if $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a base. How can I conclude from this that the union of members of $\mathcal{S}$ is $X$.

Comment: My comments were intended to help guide you to the solution, but you seem to have ignored them. So I'm not sure what to say besides "please see above".

Comment: What is the precise definition of a base?

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4868059.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base $\cal B$ is the set of intersections of finite families of members of $\cal S$. It contains in particular the intersection of an empty family, which by convention, is equal to $X$. Thus $X$ belongs to $\cal B$.

Let me insist that you **need** to use this convention. Defining $\cal B$ as the set of intersections of **nonempty** finite families of members of $\cal S$ does not work: if $\cal S$ is the empty collection, then so is $\cal B$ and $\cal B$ is not a base.

Comment: Where is the inconsistency in the last paragraph?  So an empty collection is never a subbase for a topology except on the empty space.  I agree with the convention that an empty intersection be taken as $X$ which is a way of ensuring $X$ is always included.  That doesn't make the other convention that a collection of sets $\mathcal{S}$ only defines a topology on $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ inconsistent.

Comment: @chad-k I agree with you, but we are not looking for a topology on $\bigcup \cal S$, but a topology on $X$, which is not necessarily empty...